# How to place a Circle at the middle of the corner

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have my Circle appear like this cutting the corner of the card.
I tried just making the frame bigger but that offset other things too. Is there any easy way for that?

[image]

This is what my Current Code looks like:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Robbie Williams St. Patricks Party feat. The Demons (Rock)")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(10)
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .frame(width: 62, height: 62)
                    .overlay(
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color(.init(red: 1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17, alpha: 1)))
                            .frame(width: 57, height: 57)
                            .overlay(
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Oct").font(.system(size: 10))
                                    Text("16").font(.system(size: 22))
                                }
                            )
                    )
                
            }
            Group {
                Text("Wed 19:00 - 23:00")
                    .font(.system(size: 10.5))
                    .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                Text("MTC Cologne, Cologne, Germany")
                    .font(.system(size: 10.5))
                    .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }.foregroundColor(.white)
                
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button() {
                    
                } label: {
                    Image("info").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 21, height: 21)
                        .colorInvert()
                        .padding(14)
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }.frame(width: 280, height: 160)
            .background(Color(.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use layout instruments, like alignment guides and padding, because they gives other components (like Text) react correspondingly (so, that Text, say, to wrap content)

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

***pay attention on first Text

[image: demo]

Here is modified part (a demo how it could be done conceptually - tuning is on you)

```
var body: some View {
    let edge = CGFloat(64)
    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
        Circle()
            .fill(.white)
            .frame(width: edge, height: edge)
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.init(red: 1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17, alpha: 1)))
                    .frame(width: 57, height: 57)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Text("Oct").font(.system(size: 10))
                            Text("16").font(.system(size: 22))
                        }
                    )
            )
            .zIndex(1)   // << just to keep it here but on top
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.trailing) { $0[.trailing] - edge/4}
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.top) { $0[.top] + edge/4}

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Robbie Williams St. Patricks Party feat. The Demons (Rock)")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(10)
                    .padding(.trailing, edge/2)
```

By the way... offset is evil, in wrong place ;)

Comment: So do I wrap everthing in the ZStack?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "everything", but if card - then yes. Circles will be  independent on card, like a badge. Actually you can make circle with overlay as separated view.

Comment: Actually as alternate of ZStack it is possible to do the same with .overlay over a card.

Comment: ah okay but I actually need the circle in the view and not the overlay for it to work

Answer (score 4):

Add an `.offset` to your outer `Circle()`:

```
Circle()
    .fill(.white)
    .frame(width: 62, height: 62)
    .overlay(
        Circle()
            .fill(Color(.init(red: 1, green: 0.78, blue: 0.17, alpha: 1)))
            .frame(width: 57, height: 57)
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    Text("Oct").font(.system(size: 10))
                    Text("16").font(.system(size: 22))
                }
            )
    )
    .offset(x: 15, y: -20)
```

[image]

Comment: This works but it cuts the circle off for me. https://imgur.com/a/dNGo4Y7

Comment: Are you clipping?  The code you provided doesn't clip.

Comment: This is just an overlay that lays on the card looking like this                          `struct EventCardView: View {
    var body: some View {
            Image("eventImage").resizable()
                .overlay(EventIntoOverlay())
                .frame(width: 280, height: 160)
                .cornerRadius(4)
    }
}`

Comment: You'll need to apply the circles in an overlay of the event card after the clipping (cornerRadius) has been applied.  You could pass the text to apply to the circle into EventCardView and then add the circle overlay there.